# Apache VirtualHost not directing properly

Tags: apache

I wanted to set up two virtual hosts for my apache2 running on my computer. I have inserted www.vh1.com and www.vh2.com in my hosts file in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\host. I have also created the two folders, C:\test1 and C:\test2, with the html files I want www.vh1.com and www.vh2.com to display.

However, when I opened www.vh1.com and www.vh2.com on my browser, I got re-directed to my localhost home page for www.vh2.com, and www.vh1.com showed me that web page on the Internet. Would anyone be able to help resolve this error? Would greatly appreciate it. Below is my apache httpd.conf file, minus comments:

```
ServerRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2"

Listen 80

LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so

<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>

User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin tomlin190@hotmail.com

DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI

AllowOverride AuthConfig

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

ErrorLog "logs/error.log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>

    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>

</IfModule>

<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
</IfModule>

NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/test1"
    ServerName www.vh1.com
        <Directory "c:/test1">
            Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/test2"
    ServerName www.vh2.com
        <Directory "c:/test2">
            Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>  

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

Comment: filename should be `hosts`, not `host`

Answer (score 0):

in case www.vh1.com get's you online I suspect it must be some mistake in your host file. It should resolve to localhost.

Please check this link http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/apache_vhosts.php
I have no way of testing you conf file since I only host on Linux.
Honestly i have no idea if double quote are required. I would cut them, move Directory outside VirtualHost rules.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your help. Indeed I made a typo of "1" as "l". Now, when I go to www.vh1.com, and after clearing cookies and browsing history, it gets redirected to my localhost. However, the problem remains that my VirtualHost code in Apache is not working correctly as www.vh1.com and www.vh2.com are not accessing the correct directories "c:/test1" and "c:/test2". Instead, they are accessing my "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs" directory, in the localhost code.